# Why am I getting an .aab file instead of a .apk file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to publishing to google play, but everywhere I looked says that you just click build then upload the apk file you get to google play. But the file I am receiving is an .aab file with no APK file to be found. I messed with my settings but cannot figure out why this is happening.

Thing I have tried:
1. Updating Unity
2. Change keystore file

I am not too familiar with unity, so I don't want to mess with too many settings with the risk of messing up the application further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you generate Signed Bundle or APK for release, if you select Android App Bundle you can get .aab (bundle file).

if you want to get .APK you have to select APK.

in this screen.

[image]

Comment: Is this inside android studio?

Comment: yes. you can find this in Android Studio. Build - Generate Signed Bundle / APK..